# Vertically Centered, Scrollable Columns with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to have two side-by-side columns, each 50% of the page width. The right column should be scrollable independently of the left (`overflow-y: scroll`).

The content of the right column is a table of variable height: the table should be centered if it is smaller than the page height, and the table should have padding if the table is longer than the page height (and overflow).

Here is examples of the behavior I ***WOULD*** like:

Long table that overflows:

[image: Long table that overflows]

Short table that centers:

[image: Short table that centers]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.left,
.right {
  overflow: auto;
}

.left {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
    <h1>left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <table> ... </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding that last `margin: auto` in `.right` correctly formats the table when it is small, but breaks it when the table is long and overflows (and vice-versa).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop the auto margin and instead add `align-items: center;` to your `container` and `max-height: 100vh;` to your `.left, .right` rule, you'll get what you ask for

I also changed from `width` to `flex-basis`, which is the preferred way to set a width on a flex item with row direction.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left, .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left {
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
    <h1>left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Column1</td>
        <td>Column2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
 when you set the container height to 100vh it is causing the main div to overlap a bit and you'll get a scrollbar on the left, you can remove the scrollbar by setting the parent HTML element overlap style to hidden.
Another way around it is to set container height to 90vh
but that's beside the point.
Your problem is the [.right {padding: 50px 0 50px 0;}] which is causing the right div to start from 50px and end on heigh + 50px.
You can fix this by setting the [.right {padding: 0;}].
 **Now, in order to center the table add another div around the table with the class [.tblWrapper] as described below.**

```
.tblWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -45%);//translate to 45 because the table overflows from the top of the screen on -50% (same as with the main container height 90vh instead of 100vh)
}
```

**You'll also need to add the CSS property [position: relative;] to the [.right] class**

```
.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**you can read more on this here:** https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.left,
.right {
  overflow: auto;
}

.left {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tblWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -45%); 
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
    <h1>left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='tblWrapper'>
      <table>...</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3b4761up/4/

Comment: This was helpful, but doesn't address a case in which the table is smaller. I'd like it to be centered on the page if it doesn't need to overflow.

Comment: I've made some changes to the answer in order to address your case which is how to center the table in the [.right] div.

Comment: Much closer! The translate trick is smart, but with longer tables the -50% is cutting off the top and preventing it from being displayed at all.

Comment: I've made some changes to meet your requirments

Comment: That's still a small bandage that doesn't inherently fix the problem, longer lists will still be cut off. Maybe some form of additional padding or margin on the `.right` div would help? I can't get any fixes to work.